# How to write a list of sentences into text file in Python

Tags: python, string, list, type-conversion

---

Hi. I would like to ask on how to print a list of sentences into text file. I try to use write() function to export output shown below but I couldn't get the output like in the python shell.

---

```
import os
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize, sent_tokenize
from nltk.tag import pos_tag

def preprocess():

    with open("E:\FYP 2\Error Detection Data\Data\Raw Data\D1.txt", "r") as fin, open("E:\FYP 2\Error Detection Data\Data\Raw Data\D1_edit.txt", "w") as fout:
        for sent in sent_tokenize(fin.read()):
            words = word_tokenize(sent)
            tag = pos_tag(words)
            processed_sentence = [w for w in tag]

            print (processed_sentence)
            print ("\n")

            for i in range(0,len(processed_sentence)-1):
                sentsplit = processed_sentence[i]
                fout.write('\n'.join(sentsplit))

        fin.close()
        fout.close()

preprocess()
```

Current output in text file:

Android

NNPsmartphones

NNSplay

VBPa

DTmajor

JJrole

NNin

INtoday

NN's

POSworld

NNThe

Output that I want in text file:

1. Android,NNP smartphones,NNS play,VBP a,DT major,JJ role,NN in,IN today,NN 's,POS world,NN .,.

Comment: you can use `fout.writelines(sentsplit)`.  What exactly is it about the ouput that you want to change?  Can you show us the file that this produces vs. the file you want to produce?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh i couldn't upload the image of the output. I just edit my post

Comment: And what do you want the file to look like?  Do you want a tuple on every line? What version of python are you using?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh thanks for the comment. I just edit my code using the writelines() function. But it seems that the output in the text file is not similar to the output in the python shell. It just combined all the sentences together.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I want the file to have a list of sentences which in each sentence have its tagged words. I'm using Python 3.4

Comment: You can just do `print(sentences, file=fout)` to print to the file exactly like you do to stdout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
        for i in range(0,len(processed_sentence)-1):
            sentsplit = processed_sentence[i]
            fout.write('\n'.join(sentsplit))
```

In python3 try:

```
print(processed_sentence, file=fout)
```

In python2 try:

```
print >> fout, processed_sentence
```

You also do not need to fout.close() or the fin.close() because the with context manager will handle that for you.

Comment: The output works but how can I remove the () and '' from the words?

Comment: So instead of using a single line for the print do something like (Python2):

    `for part in processed_sentence:
        print >> fout, "%s,%s" % part,`

The comma following part is important otherwise a new line is added to the output.  The code snippet here should produce what you have listed above.